# How to get a time in format hh:mm in python?

Tags: python-3.x

In my code I get the time 5:00:00 but I need it in 05:00. How can I change the format?

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
fmt = '%H%M'
ende = '1100'
start = '0600'

tdelta = datetime.datetime.strptime(ende, fmt) - datetime.datetime.strptime(start, fmt)

print(tdelta)
```

Comment: `print(str(tdelta).rsplit(":",1)[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no convenient format-specification method for `timedelta` objects, but you can just calculate the hours and minutes and format them yourself:

```
def format_delta(td):
    hours, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}'
```

Use:

```
>>> format_delta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=18000))
'05:00'
```